# Php:Proble when i convert in xml

Tags: php, xml

I want my arElemt(gurl and gname) put in . Example  and problem2 = when i write g:url or g:name = Error... php7.2* and now  example now  now i have this construction

-rss

---title

---link

---description

---gurl

---gname

i want now i have this construction

-rss

---title

---link

---description

---gurl

---gname

---gurl

---gname

---gurl

---gname i want

-rss

---title

---link

---description

---item

-----gurl

-----gname

---item

-----gurl

-----gname

---item

-----gurl

-----gname

---item

-----gurl

-----gname

```
 header("Content-type: text/xml; charset=utf-8");
    $dom = new DOMDocument('1.0','utf-8');
    $root = $dom->createElement('rss');
    $dom->appendChild($root);


    $title = $dom->createElement('title', 'test');
    $root->appendChild($title );

    $link = $dom->createElement('link', 'test');
    $root->appendChild($link );

    $description = $dom->createElement('description', 'test');
    $root->appendChild($description );


$root = $item->createElement('item');

while($arElement = $rsElements->GetNext())
{
    $url = $dom->createElement("gurl", $surl.$arElement[DETAIL_PAGE_URL]);
    $item->appendChild($url );

    $name = $dom->createElement("gname", $arElement[NAME]);
    $root->appendChild($name );

}
   echo $dom->saveXML();
    $dom->save($file_name); // save as file
```

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to do or what your actual issue is. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and edit your question accordingly. We need a detailed description of what you're trying to do and where and what goes wrong.

Comment: plz show again , i correct

Comment: I'm sorry, but I have no idea what your update suppose to show us. Also, you _still_ haven't explained _what your issues is_. We can't help you if we don't know what you need help with.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a big difference between `gurl` and `g:url`. `gurl` is not an valid RSS tag  *afaik*. `g:url` is an `url` element inside a defined namespace.

The `g` from `g:url` is a namespace prefix. It references a namespace definition. Look for a `xmlns:g` attribute in examples or for the namespace URI in the documentation of the format. The `g` is an alias for the value of that attribute. A parser resolves that to the URI internally. All the following nodes can be read as `{urn:example:namespace}url`.

- `<g:url xmlns:g="urn:example:namespace"/>`
- `<g2:url xmlns:g2="urn:example:namespace"/>`
- `<url xmlns="urn:example:namespace"/>`

RSS itself is just wellformed XML, it uses no namespace. But it can contain other XML formats that use namespaces (MediaRSS, ...).

To create an element with a namespace use the method `DOMDocument::createElementNS()`. This will automatically add the namespace definition if needed. However if do not use the namespace for the document element it will be added multiple times. You can set the namespace definition as an attribute of the reserved XMLNS namespace.

```
$data = ['one', 'two'];

// the namespace for namespace definitions
const XMLNS_XMLNS = 'http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/';
// namespace referenced by prefix g?
const XMLNS_G = 'urn:example:namespace';

$document = new DOMDocument('1.0','utf-8');
$rss = $document->appendChild(
    $document->createElement('rss')
);
// add the namespace definition to the document element
$rss->setAttributeNS(XMLNS_XMLNS, 'xmlns:g', XMLNS_G);
// create + append element node, set its text content
$rss->appendChild(
    $document->createElement('title')
)->textContent = 'test';

foreach ($data as $value) {
    $item = $rss->appendChild(
        $document->createElement('item')
    );
    // create and append an element with the namespace
    $item->appendChild(
        $document->createElementNS(XMLNS_G, 'g:url')
    )->textContent = 'http://example.com/page?'.$value;
}

$document->formatOutput = TRUE;
echo $document->saveXML();
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rss xmlns:g="urn:example:namespace">
  <title>test</title>
  <item>
    <g:url>http://example.com/page?one</g:url>
  </item>
  <item>
    <g:url>http://example.com/page?two</g:url>
  </item>
</rss>
```

- Hint 1: `DOMNode::appendChild()` returns the appended node. It is possible to nest the create call.
- Hint 2: `DOMNode::$textContent` allows to read/write the text content of a node and escapes properly.

Comment: you code is good and work, but in you <item> and one parametrs = g:url, i have more two (g:url,g:name and etc.) 
i have while operation  

When i write my data: 
while($arElement = $rsElements->GetNext()) 
{ 
    array_push($data, 
        array( 
            ''.$surl.''.$arElement["DETAIL_PAGE_URL"],
            ''.$arElement["NAME"].';', 
        )
    );

}

Comment: I don't have you're API so the example would not run directly. That is why I replaced the while loop with an foreach on a simple string list. I reduced the DOM method calls to show each variant once. You will need to replace the loop and add calls as needed.

Comment: tnk) 
while($arElement = $rsElements->GetNext())
{
    $item = $rss->appendChild(
        $document->createElement('item')
    );
    $item->appendChild(
        $document->createElementNS(XMLNS_G, 'g:url')
    )->textContent = $surl.$arElement["DETAIL_PAGE_URL"];
    $item->appendChild(
        $document->createElementNS(XMLNS_G, 'g:name')
    )->textContent = $arElement["NAME"];

  

}
its correct and work )

Comment: Not exactly, you still have to replace `urn:example:namespace` with the actual namespace  URI for that namespace.

Answer (score 0):

```
const XMLNS_XMLNS = 'http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/';
// namespace referenced by prefix g?
const XMLNS_G = 'urn:example:namespace';

$document = new DOMDocument('1.0','utf-8');
$rss = $document->appendChild(
    $document->createElement('rss')
);
// add the namespace definition to the document element
$rss->setAttributeNS(XMLNS_XMLNS, 'xmlns:g', XMLNS_G);
// create + append element node, set its text content
$rss->appendChild(
    $document->createElement('title')
)->textContent = 'test';

while($arElement = $rsElements->GetNext())
{
    $item = $rss->appendChild(
        $document->createElement('item')
    );
    $item->appendChild(
        $document->createElementNS(XMLNS_G, 'g:url')
    )->textContent = $surl.$arElement["DETAIL_PAGE_URL"];
    $item->appendChild(
        $document->createElementNS(XMLNS_G, 'g:name')
    )->textContent = $arElement["NAME"];



}
```